# Unable to resolve module error from React Native app on iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, node.js, xcode, react-native

I just joined to mobile application project which developed with React Native as a contributor. I have some issues about run the application on iPhone simulator.

Actually I achieved to run on iPhone simulator but I got error on attachment.

Let me share some details about problem.

**What did i do?**

- I got a clone from master
- I run "npm install" command on project directory
- I opened "ios" folder with xCode IDE
- I choose my developer profile as a Team (I got error without this step)
- I choose iPhone 5s as a target simulator
- And I run project on xCode.

**What's my exception?**

- Application should run correctly on simulator.

**What happened instead of my expectation?**

- Firstly, application asked from me a permission about Push Notification, then i accepted it and loaded bundle.js from React Native packager. And then I got error screen below.

[image]

**What I tried for solve this problem?**

- I suspected about my nodejs version because I don't use LTS version of Node, I used 8.4.x but also my problem still continue when I tried LTS version (6.11.4).
- I also tried this solution which I found from google.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11498

My problem is still not solved. I'm open to any idea for solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I run `node /node_modules/native-base/ejectTheme.js` command for once.

Then it's worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from your project folder: `rm -Rf ./node_modules && rm -fr package-lock.json && npm i` then `react-native run-ios`
This will reinstall your saved packages and then rebuilds the binary. Sometimes when you run `npm install some-package` it suddenly deletes a lot of other packages. Make sure you look the last line of every `npm install` log. If it says `Added x packages` and there's no `removed x` you'll be good.

*(Or maybe look in the `package.json` for the necessary packages.)*

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer but it's not worked. Still I have same error.

Comment: Do you have the `<project>/node_modules/native-base/native-base-theme` directory? Isn't the `native-base-theme' dir in your project root?

Comment: There is no "native-base-theme" directory in project/node_modules/native-base/ folder.

Comment: That's the problem. You try to access it, but there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use yarn add 'module name' instead of npm install.

Comment: Will that cover the entire issue?